# http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ngRepeat/dupes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and I'm making blog in angular, but in section where I have a list of articles chrome console get me this error and list is missing. Backend I have in PHP and connection with db seems ok because when I wrote a new article data comes to database but it seems like data won't come back to frontend. I tried to google it but I can't find any useful info to solve this problem. Thank you for any advice!

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=blog%20in%20blogs&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C

Here is blog frontend:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Added</th><th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
        <td>{{ blog.title }}</td><td>{{ blog.description }}</td><td>{{ blog.added_date }}</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeData(blog.id)">x</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is angular:

```
    $scope.frmToggle = function() {
    $('#blogForm').slideToggle();
}

$http.get('./js/popData.php')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.blogs = data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        $log.error(err);
    })

$scope.pushData = function($params) {
    $http.post('./js/pushData.php',{'title':$params.title, 'description':$params.description})
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.blogs = data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            $log.error(err);
        })
}

$scope.removeData = function($params) {
    var cnfrm = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");
    if(cnfrm) {
        $http.post('./js/removeData.php', {'id':$params})
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.blogs = data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            $log.error(err);
        })
    } else {
        // 
    }

}
```

Comment: i think you shoul define $scope bfore you do the get request
$scope.blogs = [ ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="blog in blogs track by $index">
    <td>{{ blog.title }}</td><td>{{ blog.description }}</td><td>{{ blog.added_date }}</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeData(blog.id)">x</button></td>
</tr>
```

For details about dupes [check AngularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

***From the link you gave:***

> To resolve this error either ensure that the items in the collection
>   have unique identity or use the track by syntax to specify how to
>   track the association between models and DOM.
>
> The example above can be resolved by using track by $index, which will
>   cause the items to be keyed by their position in the array instead of
>   their value:

***And this may be your solution:***

Just add `track by $index`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="blog in blogs track by $index">

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `track by $index` or other unique identifier.